# get request in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have problem with django request.I dont know. I tried to do everything, but I got
'blog' object has no attribute 'get'. I want to do mini blog on my website,but it isnt working now. I would like to get all objects from database.(Sorry,If I did something wrong,I am beginner in django and tried to functions for my website) :)

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

CHOOSE =[
    ('Usual','Обычный тариф'),
    ('Premium','Премиум тариф'),
    ('Prise','Аукционный')
]


class VDSTARIFS( models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=40, primary_key= True,serialize=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name = 'Цены')
    choosen = models.CharField(max_length= 20, choices = CHOOSE, verbose_name = 'Тариф', help_text='Выбор тарифного плана.')
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 15)
   
   
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)

class blog(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=40, primary_key= True,serialize=True)
    message = models.TextField( verbose_name= 'Сообщение блога')
    titleblog = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name = 'Название')
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'admin/', verbose_name= 'Картинка' )


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.titleblog)
    
    def get_all_objects(self):  ##maybe I have troubles with it.
        queryset = self.__class__.objects.all()
```

blog.html

```
{% csrftoken %}
{% for item in message %}

{% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
import os
from polls.models import VDSTARIFS
from polls.models import blog
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
def index_view(request):
    #return HttpResponse("<h1>Hello</h1>")
     return render(request, "home.html", {})
def about(request):
     return render(request, "about.html", {})
def minecraft(request):
     return render(request, "minecraft.html",{})

def vds(request):
    HTML_STRING = render_to_string("vds.html", context = context1)
    return HttpResponse(HTML_STRING)
try:
    VDS1 = VDSTARIFS.objects.get(id=0)
    name = VDS1.name
except VDSTARIFS.DoesNotExist:
    VDS1 = None
context1 = {
    'name':name,
    'prise':VDS1,
}

def messagesblog(request,self): 
    HTML_STRING = render_to_string('blog.html')
    return HttpResponse(HTML_STRING)
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from polls import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index_view, name='home'),
    path('vds', views.vds, name='vds' ),
    path('minecraft', views.minecraft, name='minecraft' ),
    path('about', views.about, name='about'),
    path('blog', views.blog, name='blog')
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual error is probably caused by the wrong url pattern:

```
path('blog', views.blog, name='blog')
```

views.blog refers to the blog model due to:

```
from polls.models import blog
```

What you need here is the view not the model, so:

```
path('blog', views.messagesblog, name='blog')
```

Then, remove the "self" argument from your messagesblog function.
Use the "render" function from django.shortcuts and provide a context with the blog objects:

```
def messagesblog(request):
    return render(request, "blog.html", {message: blog.objects.all()})
```

That might solve your problem.
Still, there are some things you could improve.
E.g.: Don't use "id" fields in your model definitions if you don't really, really have to, as this is usually an auto-generated number (BigInt) field.
That's only one tip from an old Django veteran happy to be finally heard. You'll find out much more yourself as you proceed.

Comment: Okay, Thanks you. I'll try to do it but If I need to get not only messages? I need to get messages and blogtitle. What Can I do? I thought of function.

Comment: In your template blog.html the "item" object in your loop is  nothing but a instance of the blog model. So you can access its fields: 
{% for item in message %} 
  Title: {{item.titleblog}}
  message: {{item.message}}
{% endfor %}
So using "messages" as key (in the context of your render function and then in the template) would be more comprehensible.

Comment: Can I ask you? What is it {message: blog.objects.all()} ? Я understood  blog.objects.all (its get request , but message, what is it?

Comment: When I added your 'def' in view.py, I had error NameError at /blog
name 'message' is not defined

Comment: Sorry, it should be "message" (or "messages") in quotes. So:

`def messagesblog(request):
    return render(request, "blog.html", {"messages": blog.objects.all()})`


The dict in the render function is the context passed to the template renderer with all the variables you want to refer to in your template.

In the template

`{% for item in messages %}`
loops through the messages which are all blog objects fetched in the view.

Do you understand?

Comment: Thanks you for your time.I solved it.